# How to setup a channel form for guests?

Tags: safecracker

I've never had any need for submissions from non-members, but now I find myself in a situation where it would be easier than having the content emailed to me so that I can add it myself. Obviously, there's a risk of spam, but I'd like to give it a go at least.

However, I must admit I find the channel form helpfiles and examples a bit arcane. I am also not entirely clear on what I need to do to enable guests to posts to a particular channel. I have setup the channel so that new posts are set Pending, but I didn't see anything else of relevance in the channel settings.

I am looking to create a form with title, url (the form is for link submissions, so that's for the url for the submitted site), description, owner, email, language and category (I have those pre-set and they should only be able to pick one).

Comment: There's a few notes in the docs on setting up guests: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#allowing-guests-to-post-entries

Comment: Thank you, I completely overlooked that. I think I my brain gave up somewhere on the middle of that page, there's just so many options.

Comment: I've gotten to this so far: http://www.westeros.org/Links/Submit but I am struggling with the categories, both how to get them to display right and how to make the selection mandatory. I am also not quite grasping how/where to send people after they submit.